# Count the number of times a webservice is being called

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have a testing framework which calls many api's exposed by my framework. I just wanted to know that if there are any tools which will help me know how many times a particular webservice is called when i run a testcase.

Will need a report of the same too. As SONAR is used to for code quality. Is there anything available which can fullfill my need.

Comment: you want to check if the call is sent by the client, or if the call is received by the server?

Comment: I want to know how many times a particular webservice is being called in a given interval of time.

Comment: A java program can be used to count it.

Comment: @VishwaRatna Apart from that do we have anything like an actuator in springboot, which will give us a metrics? My requirement is not to touch the code.Maybe i can add some dependencies or annotations. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using *Mockito spies* for your counting purpose?

Creating a spy (like it is shown [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy)) on your service enables you to verify how many times your service's methods were called

For example:

```
Mockito.verify(yourService, times(n)).aGivenMethod()
```

*n* being the number of times the method *aGivenMethod* of the service *yourService* shoud have been called.

Comment: Thanks.I have tried a POC with Springboot-Prometheus. It works fine until now.

Comment: Does anybody know how to disable only a few of my rest webservices from appearing in Promotheus?